# Modification in a sql query for more results

Tags: sql, database

I have this query here:

```
$strSQL = "select sum(lhd.sasih)-sum(lhd.sasid) as sasi,lhd.kartllg as kartllg
from d2013..levizjehd lhd,supersick_db..produkt as prod
where  lhd.kartllg=prod.kodfinance 
group by lhd.kartllg"
```

Now, this query gives me two columns: sasi and kartllg
I need to extract a third column which is in `supersick_db..produkt` table column `pershkrim`
I need to extract a `prod.pershkrim` ... How can I do it?

How to modify the query?

I modified it to:

```
$strSQL = "select sum(lhd.sasih)-sum(lhd.sasid) as sasi,lhd.kartllg as kartllg, produkt.pershkrimfinance 
from d2013..levizjehd lhd
INNER JOIN supersick_db.produkt ON lhd.kartllg = prod.kodfinance 
group by lhd.kartllg";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `JOIN` and include the column name in the `SELECT`:

```
select sum(lhd.sasih)-sum(lhd.sasid) as sasi,lhd.kartllg as kartllg, produkt.pershkrim 
from d2013..levizjehd lhd
INNER JOIN supersick_db.produkt ON produckt.ID = levizjehd.ID 
where  lhd.kartllg=prod.kodfinance 
group by lhd.kartllg
```

You will have to change `produckt.ID` and `levizjehd.ID` to the corresponding identifiers in your two tables.

Comment: Thanks Darren for the suggestion..
but i just need to get prod.pershkrim, i don't need any other condition..

Comment: @alandr - What happens when you run the modified query? do you get any error message?